# How can I add "deserialization type" function as parameter

Tags: c#, json, rest, deserialization, restsharp

```
string methodURL = "package/save";
object body = new { Id = userId, amount = 17, status = true };
string returnMsg = "Ok.";

public static string AddPackage(string restReq, string msg, object body){ 
    var client = new RestClient(restApiURL);
    var request = new RestRequest(restReq, Method.POST);
    request.AddHeader("Authorization", restApiUserBasicAuth);
    request.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
    request.AddJsonBody(body);
    var response = client.Execute<RootWebPackage>(request);
    
    string returnMessage = (response.Data.success) ? msg : response.Data.message;
    
    return returnMessage;
}

public class RootWebPackage {
    public bool success { get; set; } 
    public string message { get; set; } 
    public object data { get; set; } 
    public int resultCode { get; set; } 
}

AddPackage(methodURL, returnMsg, body);
```

I have different response classes so I need to be able to change this field dynamically. How can I add  "deserialization type" function as parameter.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you could do something like the following:

```
public static string AddPackage<T>(string restReq, string msg, object body){ 
  ...
  var response = client.Execute<T>(request);

  string returnMessage = (response.Data.success) ? msg : response.Data.message;

  return returnMessage;
}
```

This is likely not syntactically correct but I believe this could be an approach.

Comment: That's invalid syntax. It should be `AddPackage<T>(string restReq, string msg, object body)`

Comment: Thank you @Aluan Haddad. Even this is slightly wrong though as I don't think you can pass through an instance of the object type you want to deserialise to but instead you have to pass through the class?

Comment: You would write `Execute<T>(...)`. You are not passing a value but a type parameter

Comment: Ok, I see what you are saying, thanks! I will update my answer to be more correct.